# Choosing oranges. I'm going to lose my mind

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

> You have 20 fruits, 16 oranges and 4 apples. You picked 2 fruits at random. Find the probability distribution of number of apples.

My attempt:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline X_i&MyAnsP_i&BookAnsP_i\\ \hline
0&^2C_0({1\over5})^0({4\over5})^2&{^{16}C_2/ ^{20}C_2}\\\hline
1&{8/25}&32/95\\\hline
2&{16/25}&3/95\\\hline
\end{array}$$

I'm not sure why book is correct, and I am wrong or vice-versa.
I'm using Bernoulli trials and the book is using Choosing function (binomial).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bernoulli trials are appropriate when the various trials are independent, e.g., if you flipped a coin a number of times in a row. Here, when you pick two fruits, the picking is done *without replacement*, so the trials are not independent.

To see how this affects the math, imagine you first pick an orange (this happens with probability $\frac{16}{20} = \frac{4}{5}$). Now what is the probability you pick a second orange? There are $15$ oranges left out of $19$ fruits, so it is $\frac{15}{19}$ -- slightly less than $\frac{4}{5}$. Thus, e.g., the $\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^2$ term in your answer is incorrect.

Comment: I swear to god replacements are gonna make me mad. Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 3):

Bernoulli trails are when you are repeating something (and independent). In this case you took 2 fruits once and that you can do on ${20\choose 2}= 190$ ways. Now if you have no apples you get ${16 \choose 2}= 120$, 1 apple  ${16 \choose 1}{4 \choose 1} =64$ and 2 apples ${4 \choose 2}= 6$.

So we have distribution: $${6\over 190}= {3\over 95}, {64\over 190} = {32\over 190}\;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;{120\over 190}= {60\over 95}$$